# Unity3D transform.position.x keeps setting to 0

Tags: c#, position, unity-game-engine, transform

The weirdest thing keeps happening and I can not figure out why. Instead of just setting up like 20 different prefabs, I wanted to instatiate them in my code. I am making a Space Invaders C# game and I got the first row of invaders to spawn fine using the code found below. Literally no issues at all, and they move how I want them too as well. But as soon as I set up my second row the transform.position syntax that I used for the first row, suddenly does not apply and it just sets my transform.position.x to 0. I do have another class that MIGHT be the reason, but so far I have not found any solution to this problem. Thanks for help in advance.

```
//GameController Class
//
//globals
//
Quaternion roto;
public Vector3 newPos;
public float addInvader
bool spawnInvader = true;
public GameObject invaders;
//
void Update()
{
    newPos = transform.position;
    roto = transform.rotation;

    newPos2 = transform.position;
    roto2 = transform.rotation;

    if (addInvader <= 0f) 
    {
        SpawnInvaders ();
    }

    if (addInvader > 0f) 
    {
        SpawnInvaders ();
    }


    if (addInvader > 5f)
    {
        spawnInvader = false;
    }

    if (add2Invader <= 0f) 
    {
        //invaderSrow();
    }

    if (add2Invader > 0f)
    {
        //invaderSrow();
        secondrow = false;
    }
}

void SpawnInvaders()
{
    if (spawnInvader) 
    {
        if (addInvader < 1f)
        {
            newPos.x = 900f;
            newPos.y = 0f;
            newPos.z = 800f;
            roto.z = 180f;
            Instantiate (invaders, newPos, roto);
            addInvader++;
        }

        if (addInvader == 1f)
        {
            newPos.x = 700f;
            newPos.y = 0f;
            newPos.z = 800f;
            roto.z = 180f;
            Instantiate (invaders, newPos, roto);
            addInvader++;
        }

        if (addInvader == 2f)
        {
            newPos.x = 500f;
            newPos.y = 0f;
            newPos.z = 800f;
            roto.z = 180f;
            Instantiate (invaders, newPos, roto);
            addInvader++;
        }

        if (addInvader == 3f)
        {
            newPos.x = 300f;
            newPos.y = 0f;
            newPos.z = 800f;
            roto.z = 180f;
            Instantiate (invaders, newPos, roto);
            addInvader++;
        }

        if (addInvader == 4f)
        {
            newPos.x = 100f;
            newPos.y = 0f;
            newPos.z = 800f;
            roto.z = 180f;
            Instantiate (invaders, newPos, roto);
            addInvader++;
        }

        if (addInvader == 5f)
        {
            newPos.x = -600f;
            //newPos2.x = newPos2.x - 200f;
            newPos.y = 0f;
            newPos.z = 500f;
            roto.z = 180f;
            Instantiate (invaders, newPos, roto);
            addInvader++;
        }
    }

    return;

}

void invaderSrow()
{
    InvaderController F = new InvaderController();
    //F.newX = newPos2.x;

    if (secondrow)
    {
        if (add2Invader < 1f) 
        {
            newPos.x = -800f;
            newPos.y = 0f;
            newPos.z = 500f;
            roto.z = 180f;
            //Instantiate (invaders2, newPos, roto);
            add2Invader++; //add2Invader should be 1 now....
            //secondrow = false;
        }

        if (add2Invader == 1f) 
        {
            newPos2 = transform.position;
            newPos2.x = -800f + 200f;
            //F.newX = -800f;
            //F.newX = newPos2.x + 200f;
            newPos2.y = 0f;
            newPos2.z = 500f;
            roto2.z = 180f;
            //Instantiate (invaders3, newPos2, roto2);
            add2Invader++;
        }


    }
    return;

}
//InvaderController class
//
//globals
//
public float newX;
public float invaderSpeed;
public float resistance;

public GameObject Invader;
public GameObject explosion;

Quaternion rotation;
//
    void Awake() 
{
    firstxoff = true;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{

    if (firstxoff == true)
    {
        firstmove ();
    }
        moveX1 ();
}



void firstmove()
{
    Vector3 newPos = transform.position;
    newPos.x -= invaderSpeed;
    transform.position = newPos;


    if (newPos.x < -900f) //moves z
    {
        Vector3 newPosZ = transform.position;
        newPosZ.z -= invaderSpeed;
        float x = -900f;
        newX = x;
        newPosZ.x = newX;
        transform.position = newPosZ;

    }

}

void moveX1()
{
    Vector3 newPos = transform.position;
    if (newPos.z <= 500f)
    {
        Vector3 newPosX = transform.position;
        newX = newX + invaderSpeed;
        float z = 500f;
        newZ = z;
        newPosX.z = newZ;
        newPosX.x = newX;
        transform.position = newPosX;


        if (newPosX.x  > -900f)
        {
        newX = newX + (invaderSpeed + 7f);
        firstxoff = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW: Your rotation appears wrong as you set quaternion.z directly instead of `Quaternion.EulerAngles`.

Comment: I am new to this, but the rotation is fine nothing is wrong with that. Even the transform.z changes to 500 it's only the transform.x that keeps going to 0

Comment: Okay so when I stopped calling "movex1" in my Update function in my InvaderClass the invader spawned at -600. So I know my problem is in the movex1 function, if that helps anyone trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

in moveX1() you are using newX  , is it possible you are sometimes calling moveX1 before firstMove ?  if so then newX would be undefined and 0.

Comment: No, (or at least I don't think so?). if firstxoff is true (which i set it true in start) then it runs firstMove. firstMove runs fine, the movement of everything is fine i just can't understand why it sets the position to 0 but i know it has something to do with moveX1()

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Added a `newX = newPosX.x;` line at the start of my moveX1() function :D thanks everyone who tried!